# Using Selenium WebDriver in C#, how do I access the text between the opening and closing div tags?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So a page I'm looking at has a line:

```
<div class="page-curr">Page 1 of 10</div>
```

I assumed a simple

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("page-curr")).Text
```

would work. There are no other iterations of page-curr on the page. It seems to find the node when I remove the .Text, but the Text in that node is empty. I suppose I'm simply looking in the wrong spot for it, but I'm not sure where I'd find it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a WebDriverWait()? My guess is that it's a timing thing.

Comment: Use `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("page-curr")).GetAttribute("textContent")`;

Comment: As @JeffC  mentioned add `WebDriverWait()` it is nothing but synchronization issue.

Comment: @KunduK Don't use `.GetAttribute("textContent")`. it doesn't do anything differently than `.Text` does except it will fail in some browsers.

Comment: KunduK's solution actually worked for me. Thanks for the WebDriverWait bit as I have actually hit that before and could use the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Using an [explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) for the contents of the tag to be "not empty" should do the trick:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

wait.Until(d => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.FindElement(By.ClassName("page-curr")).Text));

var text = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("page-curr")).Text;
```